# Clocks at different redshift: does calculating luminosity distance shift the frame of reference?

Tags: cosmology, reference-frames, space-expansion, redshift, luminosity

Luminosity is energy per time.

When we calculate a luminosity distance, using angular diameter distance times $(1+z)^2$, I think we are correcting the energy (from redshifted photons) by $(1+z)$ and the time (the distance between them has increased) by $(1+z)$ as well.

Doesn't that create a bit of a problem? On one end of a distance is an observer with a clock, and on the other end of the same distance is a clock going at $1/(1+z)$. This distance seems to cross between two frames of reference?

The luminosity should depend on a clock, and the clock of an observer and the clock in the rest frame of a distant galaxy should differ by a factor of $(1+z)$.

If we use our clock to measure flux, then luminosity is measured by that clock too. Does it make sense then that the luminosity distance calculation should "correct" for time dilation?